# Reflexive, Symmetric, Transitive for (a,b)E R iif (a-b) is a multiple of k

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If k is any positive integer, and R is a relation on the set 0,1,2,3 as (a,b) are elements of R iif (a-b) is a multiple of k.

Is R reflexive, symmetric and/or transitive.

I know reflexive means x=x; symmetric if x=y, y=x; and transitive is x=y, y=z, x=z. However am unsure how to apply such to this question to prove it.

Any help would be valued.

Comment: You should write both the question (what is $q$?) and what you know more carefully. Even meeting you half-way by assuming "$x=y$" means "$(x,y) \in R$" there are certainly some things missing (like an "if... then..." statement).

Comment: Are you sure you mean if $ab$ is a multiple of $k$, and not $a-b$ is a multiple of $k$? Let $k = 3$. Then $1^{2}$ and $2^{2}$ are both not multiples of $3$. But for any integer $x$, $x - x = 0$, which is a multiple of $k$.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally typed q instead of k. I apologize.  And yes, I meant a-b is a multiple of k. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what your relation is, but I will answer your question for both ways I could interpret your relation (hopefully I'm not missing a different way):

**First way of interpreting your relation:**

Let $S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. We define a relation, $R_1$ to be $R_1 = \{(a, b) : a, b \in S, ~~k|(a-b) ~~ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}\}$

**Second way of interpreting your relation:**

Let $S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, and fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We define a relation, $R_2$ to be $R_2 = \{(a, b) : a, b \in S, ~~k|(a-b)\}$

**First interpretation:**

Reflexivity: For all $a \in S$, $a-a=0$. We also know that: $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, $k|0$. So this relation is reflexive.

Symmetric: If $a, b \in S$ are such that $k|(a-b) ~~ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, we also have $k|(b-a) ~~\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ as $(b-a) = -(a-b)$. So this relation is symmetric.

Transitivity: If $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $k|(a-b)$, and $k|(b-c)$, we have $(a-c) = (a-b + b - c) = (a-b) + (b-c)$, and thus $k|(a-c)$, for every $k$. So this relation is transitive

Interestingly enough, this is a way to represent the relation of equality over a subset of the Natural numbers. (Note that the only number, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $k|n ~~\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ is $n = 0$, which means $(a, b) \in R$ if and only if $a-b = 0$ if and only if $a = b$.

**Second Interpretation**

Reflexivity:
Fixing a $k$, for every $a \in S$, $a-a =0$. As we just noted, every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ divides $0$. So for any $k$, this relation is reflexive.

Symmetric:
If $k|(a-b)$, we do indeed have $k|(b-a)$, as, again, $(a-b) = -(b-a)$. So this relation is symmetric.

Transitive: 
Similar to the proof in the first interpretation, if  $k|(a-b)$, and $k|(b-c)$, we have $(a-c) = (a-b + b - c) = (a-b) + (b-c)$, and thus $k|(a-c)$. So this relation is also transitive.

While the proofs progressed similarly, in the second interpretation of the relation, we do not have $(a, b) \in R$ if and only if $a = b$. For example, setting $k = 2$, we observe that $(0, 2) \in R_2$. But $(0, 2)$ is not in $R_1$, as 2 is not divisible by every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.